# openseadragon throwing error if i use IF condition to the parent div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openseadragon

I am implementing openseadragon in my angular4 project,

If I use like below it's not working and throwing error **Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null,

```
<div *ngIf="(pictures$ | async).length" >
    <div id="seadragon-viewer" style="height: 333px;color: #333;background-color: black;">
     </div>
</div>
```

But if I use directly true in my IF condition then it's working perfectly,

```
<div *ngIf="true" >
    <div id="seadragon-viewer" style="height: 333px;color: #333;background-color: black;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Cannot able to solve this , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please could you share more information

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora pictures data is coming from ngrx store, i have to excute my zoom functionality only if there is a picture, that's why i am checking pictures length.

But if i use ngif it throwing error like Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Answer (score 0):

In your component make a variable `showSeaDragon: boolean = false;`

When the loading of the `pictures$` is done set the boolean to `true` when `pictures$.length>0`

```
<div *ngIf="showSeaDragon" >
```

Comment: When you log the value to the console the value is true?

Comment: yes it's true, but it is throwing error Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Answer (score 0):

IN your ts file you are doing `appendChild` by fetching element by Id `seadragon-viewer`. In second case your element will be always present in the DOM so it is working fine. When `*ngIf` becomes `false` it removes entire element from DOM so you are getting this error. You can do two things.

1. use `[hidden]` in place of `*ngIf`.
2. before using `appendChild` check the value of fetched element (preferred).